# Terraform get tfvars file from remote repository

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have .tfvars file in remote repository for some other infrastructure. I want to reuse the config file. I am working on new infrastructure but need to use the content of .tfvars. So far tried the following but I am not sure how to read the file I got via http url. Is there a better way of getting remote config?

```
data "http" "tfvars" {
  url = "https://some@dev.azure.com/some/_git/sampleinfra?path=/infra/variable_folders.auto.tfvars"
  request_headers = {
    Accept = "application/json"
  }
}
```

I want to add that the content of the file is json array

```
    folderList = {   
    "main" = {
        process= true
    }   
    "base" = {
        process= false
    }
  }
```

Comment: There are always attributes that get exported with data sources, based on your question I guess you want something like: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/http/latest/docs/data-sources/http#response_body.

Comment: Which of attributes I need and how to use them ?

Comment: That's a question for you. :) I don't know which you need. But you probably want to filter something from the response you get. So the URL from my previous comment should be a place to start.

Comment: I probably not described myself clearly, how do I process this file data.http.tfvars  in terraform?